# RISC-V: Illegal instruction exception when switching to supervisor mode

Tags: qemu, riscv, low-level

When setting the `mstatus.mpp` field to switch to supervisor mode, I'm getting an illegal instruction exception when calling `mret`. I'm testing this in `qemu-system-riscv64` version 6.1 with the `riscv64-softmmu` system.
I recently upgraded from QEMU 5.0 to 6.1. Prior to this upgrade my code worked. I can't see anything relevant in the changelog. I'm assuming that there's a problem in my code that the newer version simply doesn't tolerate.

Here is a snippet of assembly that shows what's happening (unrelated boot code removed):

```
.setup_hart:
    csrw satp, zero                                # Disable address translation.

    li   t0, (1 << 11)                             # Supervisor mode.
    csrw mstatus, t0

    csrw mie, zero                                 # Disable interrupts.

    la  sp, __stack_top                            # Setup stack pointer.

    la   t0, asm_trap_vector
    csrw mtvec, t0

    la   t0, kernel_main                           # Jump to kernel_main on trap return.
    csrw mepc, t0

    la   ra, cpu_halt                              # If we return from main, halt.
    mret
```

If I set the `mstatus.mpp` field to `0b11` for machine mode, I can get to `kernel_main` without any problem.

Here's the output from QEMU showing the exception information:

```
riscv_cpu_do_interrupt: hart:0, async:0, cause:0000000000000002, epc:0x000000008000006c, tval:0x0000000000000000, desc=illegal_instruction
```

`mepc` points to the address of the `mret` instruction where the exception occurs.
I've tested that the machine supports supervisor mode by writing and retrieving the value in `mstatus.mpp` successfully.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? My code seems very similar to the few examples I can find online, such as https://osblog.stephenmarz.com/ch3.2.html. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue turned out to be RISC-V's *Physical Memory Protection* (PMP). QEMU will raise an *illegal instruction* exception when executing an `MRET` instruction if no PMP rules have been defined. Adding a PMP entry resolved the issue.

This was confusing, as this behaviour is not specified in the *Privileged Architecture* manual's section on `mret`.

Comment: I am trying to run some code on `qemu-riscv32` and also get an `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`. It appears that the instruction causing the issue is a write to `mstatus`. How did you go about creating a PMP entry?

Comment: I guess qemu is running in S or U mode. How can I get qemu to run in M mode?

Comment: RISC-V systems enter M mode on initialisation. Your question is more complicated than I can answer here. It depends on so many other factors. Your best bet is to ask a full question about this.

Comment: Thanks for figuring that out. I had the exact same issue and configuring the PMP solved it!